# JTable in JTabbedPane_TabPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have made a little minimum example.
I have a jTabbedPane with two tabs.
After pressing a button in TabPanel2 a table shut showing up.
But the table does not appear.
Please help me. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class test extends JFrame {
  private JButton jButton1 = new JButton();
  private JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
  private JPanel jTabbedPane1TabPanel1 = new JPanel(null, true);
  private JPanel jTabbedPane1TabPanel2 = new JPanel(null, true);
  private JButton jButton2 = new JButton();

  public void jButton2_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {   
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0,2);
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {"string1","string2"});
    JTable table1 = new JTable(tableModel);
    jTabbedPane1TabPanel2.add(table1); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your specific case, you should show more of your code. Give the whole class with all the irrelevant lines removed, including a main where the JFrame is instantiated. Lots of MCVE's to be found out there. But chances are good that your jTabbedPane_1TabPanel1 was never added to some container that *is* displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    `public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

     private JButton jButton1 = new JButton("button1");
     private JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
     private JPanel jTabbedPane1TabPanel1 = new JPanel();
     private JPanel jTabbedPane1TabPanel2 = new JPanel();
     private JButton jButton2 = new JButton("button2");

     public test() {
     jTabbedPane1TabPanel1.add(jButton1);
     jTabbedPane1TabPanel2.add(jButton2, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
     jTabbedPane1.addTab("1", jTabbedPane1TabPanel1);
     jTabbedPane1.addTab("2", jTabbedPane1TabPanel2);
     jButton2.addActionListener(this);
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setContentPane(jTabbedPane1);
     frame.pack();
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true);
     }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, 2);
     tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {
        "string1", "string2"
     });
    JTable table1 = new JTable(tableModel);
    // System.out.println(table1.getColumnCount());
    // System.out.println(table1.getRowCount());
    jTabbedPane1TabPanel2.add(table1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new test();
    }

   }`
```

Comment: Check this out: